# Can someone help me make this SQL query more efficient?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    datepart(qq, o.created_date),
    count(DISTINCT o.order_id),
    sum(o.order_margin)
FROM
    orders o
WHERE  
    o.account_id IN (SELECT e.account_id
                     FROM emailsegment e
                     WHERE e.segment = 'H')
    AND o.created_date >= '1/1/2016'
    AND o.order_status = 'Shipped'
GROUP BY 
    datepart(qq, o.created_date)
ORDER BY 
    datepart(qq, o.created_date)
```

This is taking forever to run, any ideas?

Comment: sounds like you might have an index or two missing.. query isn't that bad.

Comment: Please post your execution plan and description of any indexes on your tables.

Comment: Can you post the table and index definitions?

Comment: You do want to be careful with date strings though. You should use the ANSI standard yyyy-mm-dd to avoid any localization issues.

Comment: do you need `count(distinct o.order_id)`? is `order_id` not the primary key of table `orders`?  if it is you can just use `count(o.order_id)`

Comment: Even if you have index on createddate,SQLmight not take advantage of it,try creating some table which defines you quarter start and end and  use join and check

Comment: Did you try moving the select subquery in where clause outside and doing a join? Also try the query step by step and see which step is causing the query to take long time. For example first pull all records from orders with the where clause. May be you can first skip the select subquery. Then add it and see how it behaves. And so on keep adding each step.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance here, but would a CTE help with the `IN` clause, or does SQL Server recognize that as a static list and re-use the result instead of rebuilding per record?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    datepart(qq, o.created_date),
    count(DISTINCT o.order_id),
    sum(o.order_margin)
FROM
    orders o
INNER JOIN 
    emailsegment e ON e.account_id = o.account_id AND e.segment = 'H'
WHERE  
    o.created_date >= '2016-01-01'
    AND o.order_status = 'Shipped'
GROUP BY 
    datepart(qq, o.created_date)
ORDER BY 
    datepart(qq, o.created_date)
```

Comment: This would have to assume that `account_id + segment` is unique for `emailsegment`, otherwise the `sum` would be overstated, right?.

Comment: @JoeEnos Also within datepart(qq,o.created_date), but yes, there is a potential here. I can re-write using an APPLY instead that might also be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just several wild guesses:

1. How many records returns following query and how long it is taking to run?

`SELECT e.account_id FROM emailsegment e WHERE  e.segment = 'H';`

It might be beneficial to create an index on `account_id` with filter on `segment` column.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_account_id_emailsegment ON emailsegment(account_id)
WHERE segment = 'H'
```

Or

```
CREATE INDEX ix_segment_emailsegment ON emailsegment(segment)
INCLUDE (account_id)
```

2. Depending which number of filtered records is smaller `created_date >= '1/1/2016'` or `o.account_id IN (` or `o.order_status = 'Shipped'` that column has to be the first column within an index. Would say it will be `created_date` then you have to create an index like:

`CREATE INDEX ix_created_date_orders 
    on orders(created_date, account_id, order_id)
    INCLUDE (order_margin)
    WHERE order_status = 'Shipped';`

If your column `order_id` is a clustered index then you do not have include it into the index.

3. You can try to add word `DISTINCT` into your sub-query. Not sure if that will help.